# Laravel 4.x, using both controller & resource routing

Tags: laravel, resources, laravel-routing

I'm trying using this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

When I'm using one of them - WORK,
otherwise - only resource work.

There is an option to using them both?

Comment: How are you using them?  Can you show some examples of how you are linking your users to them, etc...?

Comment: localhost/users/example -> doesn't work, every else resource function worked well. I'm using "public function getExample()"

Answer (score 0):

Which ever is on-top will take priority so if you put Route::controller on-top then that's the one that would work. I would post this as a comment but I don't have the rep to do it. Also why would you wanna use both of them at the same time?

Comment: btw not that it's wrong but its better in the long run from experience if you individually name each route much easier for debugging and you can see exactly what is happening and not depend on Laravel's "magic"

Comment: Simply, I want easly add functions without routing many options.. but also preserve resource functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `Route::controller` declaration above `Route::resource`:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

The thing is that Laravel tries to match request with your defined routes by going from top to bottom and stops when it finds one.

`localhost/users/example` in your example actually hits `show` method in your `UserController` class as explained in [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) (see **Actions Handled By Resource Controller**).

Therefore `Route::controller('users', 'UserController');` is ignored in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's only working with one because once you use `Route::resource()`, all routes starting with `users` is going to be grabbed, and since `Route::resource()` does not work by prepending the action with the last segement in the uri (`public function getUsers()`), it's failing.

With your example provided, all you should need to use is `Route::controller()`.  If there are some cases where that won't do, before it, add whatever routes you need using `Route::get()`, `Route::post()` or `Route::any()`

`Route::resource()` and `Route::controller()` were I believe not designed to work together and there shouldn't be much need to actually use them together.